# How to append p:calendar to a specific element?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to append a PrimeFaces [Calendar](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml) input component to the following DOM element:

```
<div id="main-container" />
```

I have tried the following two approaches:

```
<p:calendar appendTo="@(#main-container)" />
```

and

```
<p:calendar appendTo="@([id$=main-container])" />
```

Unfortunately, none of them work. The calendar is still the child of the body element. I can't find anywhere on the documentation what's the search expression's syntax supposed to look like in these situations so I'm not sure if my syntax is correct or if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: PrimeFaces calendar does not have the appendTo attribute. It is not in the documentation (at least not the 6.1)

Answer (score 1):

You can just put your calendar inside the div you want.

In the case you need to update some other div when select the date, just put the id on update(ajax).

```
<div class="col s12 m3 input-field" id="div_fromDate">
        <p:outputLabel for="myDate" value="My date" />
        <p:calendar id="myDate" value="#{myBean.myDate}">
            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="divToUpdate"/>
        </p:calendar>
</div>
<div id="divToUpdate">

</div>
```

Otherwise Primefaces/jsf doesn't work correctly with `div`, you will have to use `panelGroup` sometimes.

Hope this help you a little!